# Extract columns into a new table and create an FK to new table at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an existing SQL Server database with a Customers table that has columns:

```
Customers:  CustomerId (PK), A, B, C, D, E, F
```

The last three columns represent a postal address; I want to extract those address columns into a separate Addresses table, linked by an FK, and migrate the data at the same time.  So I that end up with:

```
Customers:  CustomerId (PK), A, B, C, AddressId (FK)

Addresses:  AddressId (PK), D, E, F
```

Address will eventually be referenced by many other tables also, so it needs its own independent AddressId, database-generated -  it can't share the same Id as the Customer. Nor can the Address contain an FK to Customer  -  the schema has to be as shown.

I am not very fluent with SQL.  I have no difficulty creating the new Addresses table, copying the data across, and then deleting the redundant columns from Customers, in SQL. But I don't know how to get the the database-generated AddressId back into the Customer as an FK.  Do I need to resort to some kind of procedural approach using e.g. a cursor   -  or is there any way to do this whole migration in one declarative SQL query?  Thanks.

(N.B.  I'd like to be able to do this ultimately within Code First Migrations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out the answer. You have to use Merge, in order to be able to output columns from both the source and target tables into a temp table:

```
Declare @MyTableVar table(
 CustomerId int not null,
 AddressId int not null
);

Merge into dbo.Addresses    
using (select CustomerId, D,E,F from dbo.Customers) as addressDetails
on 1=0
when not matched then 
insert ( D,E,F) values ( Customers.D, Customers.E, Customers.F)
output addressDetails.CustomerId, inserted.AddressId into @MyTableVar;
update Customers  set AddressId =
 (Select AddressId from @MyTableVar where CustomerId = Customers.CustomerId );
```